# Getting the error The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, http-status-code-404

Getting the error origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatcher servlet does not where to dispatch the request. Issue is your controller bean is not created/working.

Even I faced the same problem. Then added the following under mvc-config.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.nsv.jsmbaba.teamapp.controller"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix"><value>/WEB-INF/view/</value></property>
    <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
</bean>
```